# How to define a generic function to derive multiple new columns from a given column name?

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, multiple-columns

I have been trying to derive two columns from a given column name through a python function.  Below is the code snippet:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring

def deriveCol(source_col_name, col1, col2):
    df.select(source_col_name, substring(source_col_name, 1, 4).alias(col1), substring(source_col_name, 5, 2).alias(col2))
    for i in col2:
        if i >= "01" and i <= "03":
            print("First quarter")
        elif i >= "04" and i <= "06":
            print("second quarter")
        elif i >= "06" and i <= "09":
            print("Third quarter")
        else:
            print("Fourth quarter")
    return df.select([col1, col2]).show(10, truncate=True)
 
t = deriveCol("Report", "year", "month")
```

Please see the below output

```
Fourth quarter
Fourth quarter
+----+-----+
|year|month|
+----+-----+
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
|2022|   01|
+----+-----+
only showing top 10 rows
```

"Report' = the source column from where data has to be derived from.
"year"/"month" = derived column.

I have a column coming for a database table, and I have to split it into 3 parts: "year", "month", "quarter".

The "year" and "month" were easy. But finding the "quarter" is not working. When executing the code, it's directly going to `else` and printing "fourth quarter". But I can say that the "month" which I have derived above with the help of `substring()` function also has dates coming from all months of a given year.

Note: I need to save the output of the "quarter" in a separate column.

Comment: How do your "Report" column values look like?

Comment: 20220101, this as an example

Comment: yyyyMMdd, this is the format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first step I have created a true *date* column out of *string*. Having the *date* column we can apply methods `year`, `month` and `quarter`.

```py
def derive_col(source_col_name, col1, col2, col3):
    date_col = F.to_date(source_col_name, 'yyyyMMdd')
    df = df.select(
        *[c for c in df.columns if c != source_col_name],
        F.year(date_col).alias(col1),
        F.month(date_col).alias(col2),
        F.quarter(date_col).alias(col3)
    )
    return df
```

Full test, using one more `df` parameter, as I cannot use the function without it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('20220101',), ('20220731',)], ['Report'])

def derive_col(df, source_col_name, col1, col2, col3):
    date_col = F.to_date(source_col_name, 'yyyyMMdd')
    df = df.select(
        *[c for c in df.columns if c != source_col_name],
        F.year(date_col).alias(col1),
        F.month(date_col).alias(col2),
        F.quarter(date_col).alias(col3)
    )
    return df

df = derive_col(df, 'Report', 'year', 'month', 'quarter')

df.show()
# +----+-----+-------+
# |year|month|quarter|
# +----+-----+-------+
# |2022|    1|      1|
# |2022|    7|      3|
# +----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot hard code the date range in my code. I am creating a function, which could be called by other users in their program and pass their own parameters. Please suggest

Comment: What do you mean? Date range is not hardcoded - you can apply any date. Did you mean the date format? But then your users will need to provide the format themselves.

Comment: All I was saying that the kind of data I have with me they can fall anywhere between 2009 and 2022 . So, the way you have declared  df = "spark.createDataFrame([('20220101',), ('20220731',)], ['Report'])", will it work in my case? Plz suggest

Comment: That is just an example. Just apply your dataframe instead of mine. The `def` is the function. Use that function with your data.